# Push-out of product of push-out diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, category-theory

Let $\pi(U\cup V)$ be the push-out of the diagram $\pi(U)\leftarrow \pi(U\cap V) \rightarrow \pi(V)$ that appears when we apply Vam-Kampen Theorem to the open sets $U,V$ in a topological space $X$. Moreover, im working with a variety $X$, so i can assume that the morphisms are surjective and the groups finitely generated.

Now, consider the diagram * $\pi(U)\times G_1 \leftarrow \pi(U\cap V)\times G_{12}\rightarrow \pi(V)\times G_2$ induced by the above diagram, and the diagram
$G_1\leftarrow G_{12}\rightarrow G_2$ (with push-out $G$) of surjections of finitely generated abelian groups.

1. Is the push-out of * isomorphic to $\pi(U\cup V) \times G$?

I think that it is true, by proceding with generators and relations.

How much this argument can be genralized? 
For example, in the category of fundamental groups ( fundamental groups of topological spaces) the push-out commute with the product of the diagrams ( by applying Van-Kampen Theorem on the product of the spaces). In the category of abelian groups it is true again, but in the category of groups this is false.

1. In which other subcategories of the category of groups is this true?

Thanks in advance.